# Improving performance in batch ffmpeg video corruption detecting script

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg, corrupt

As of recent I have realized that some .mkv video files I have were corrupted. As such I wrote a very basic batch script to check the files for errors and output any errors into a text file. This script is quite slow and I have many videos, as such I was wondering how I could improve the performance of the script. I was thinking I could improve performance by using gpu acceleration but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work. Any ideas would be welcome.

Here is my code:

```
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
echo %%a >> ErrorDetectionInProgress.txt
"I:\@Advanced\ffmpeg-20151224-git-4707497-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -loglevel error -i "%%a" -f null - 2>> ErrorDetectionInProgress.txt
echo. >> ErrorDetectionInProgress.txt
)
move ErrorDetectionInProgress.txt ErrorList.txt
```

Comment: If you are checking for errors in the video coding layer, such as missing/incorrect reference slices..etc then all frames have to be decoded. How did you try h/w accel?

Comment: This question might belong to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mulvya I tried using hardware acceleration by using "I:\@Advanced\ffmpeg-20151224-git-4707497-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -hwaccel auto -loglevel error -i "%%a" -f null - 2>> ErrorDetectionInProgress.txt

Comment: Over here, enabling hwaccel results in 1/3rd slower performance. One possibility, if the errors in a corrupt file aren't randomly distributed, is to test only sections of a file e.g. `ffmpeg.exe -loglevel error -ss 25 -t 5 -i "%%a" ...` . Maybe two or three commands per file.

Comment: @Mulvya Hey, seems like the corruption is pretty rare and random. Thanks anyway, i'll probably just keep doing it the way I have been.